# How do I display time in 24-hour format in TextClock?

Tags: android, time, clock

I am having trouble to display time in 24-hour format in TextClock. I got it to display time in another time zone, but I can't get it to display in 24-hour format.

```xml
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/hk_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timeZone="GMT+0800"
    android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy k:mm" />
```

Also, is it possible to display a date in TextClock?

Answer (score 16):

If your system is in 12-hour mode, you shouldn't have to write a subclass to get what you want. The [JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) say:

> - In 12-hour mode:
>
>   - Use the value returned by getFormat12Hour() when non-null
>   - Otherwise, use the value returned by getFormat24Hour() when non-null
>   - Otherwise, use a default value appropriate for the user's locale, such as HH:mm

Therefore, I would expect the last line in this to make `getFormat12Hour()` return `null` and thus use your custom `getFormat24Hour()` format:

```xml
<android.widget.TextClock
    android:id="@+id/hk_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timeZone="GMT+0800"
    android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy k:mm"
    android:format12Hour="@null" />
```

(BTW, as others have mentioned, forced formats should be used with care. If your users wanted a 24-hour clock, they would have specified this in their system preferences. And apps that force numerically formatted, topsy-turvy date formats on their users, like `MM/dd/yyyy`, invite one-star ratings (except, in this case, from US and Filipino users), so it's a good thing you're using `MMM`! You'd still be better off using [getBestDateTimePattern()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getBestDateTimePattern%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String%29), though, which, I believe, would require subclassing TextClock.)

Comment: Michael Scheper, I am wondering how can I remove the PM or AM from showing in my textClock?

Comment: To see all options for the date format string: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @VictorRendina: Indeed. But once again, care should be taken to use those options in a locale-independent way. `h:mm a` will be confusing for users who live in places that don't use AM/PM, and if you hardcode `MM/dd/yyyy`, then about 40% of the time, users outside of the US and the Philippines simply won't be able to tell that the date they're looking at has a foreign format. _Billions of people will think your app is wrong or confusing,_ so in most cases, you should use `full`, `long`, `short`, etc., instead of custom, hard-coded formats.

Answer (score 8):

My device using 12h format. To force it to use 24h format, I write this:

```
textClock.setFormat12Hour("kk:mm");
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of set time format in xml i'm suggest to use with java file i.e

```
mTextClock.setFormat24Hour(format);
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Kotlin**

I used this line for making time format to 24-Hours and it's working fine.

```
mTextClock.format12Hour = "kk:mm"
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you:

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/tc_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="h:mm:ss a - d MMM, yyyy"
    android:format24Hour="k:mm:ss - d MMM, yyyy"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether it shows the time in 12- or 24-hour format depends on the system setting. Perhaps your Android device or emulator is set to 12-hour format. That is why your `android:format24Hour`is ignored. If you would like to show the 24-hour format by overwriting the system setting (which I would not recommend), add `android:format12Hour="MMM dd, yyyy k:mm"` as another attribute.

However, it is always recommended to show the time and date according to the system setting. If there are some other (e.g. layout) constraints in your app that require separate handling of 12- or 24-hour mode, you can check the setting dynamically in code by calling `is12HourModeEnabled()` or `is24HourModeEnabled()` on your `TextClock`.

To your second question, the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) say

> TextClock can display the current date and/or time as a formatted
>   string.

and that's what it is capable of -- display a the time *and* date. If you mean "another date than the current", you would have to stick to a simple `TextView` and format the date String manually.

Comment: how would i change it to add in the date?

Comment: I'm not sure about your understanding of a "date", but if you mean day, month and year, isn't that already included in your `"MMM dd, yyyy k:mm"` format?

Answer (score 0):

*1st question:*

I've just checked it and when on your device is set:

- 12-h format(US, GB) - TextClock is 12h
- 24-h format(Europe) - TextClock is 24h

As mentioned above, it's better when you'll give the choice to the user and you won't force him to use ex. your favorite format.

*2nd question:*

Yes, it is. You just need to use "android:format12Hour" and/or "android:format24Hour".

```
android:format12Hour="MMM dd, yyyy"
android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy"
```

**MMM** means 3 characters for a month's name

**dd** means 2 characters for a day

**yyyy** means 4 characters for a year